# android: RuntimeException when using async

Tags: android, android-asynctask, nullpointerexception

I'm developing a simple application for parsing RSS feed, because of getting `NetworkOnMainThreadException` error, I had to write my code using Async:

```
protected List<RSSItem> data;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        GetDataRSS getDataRSS = new GetDataRSS();
        getDataRSS.execute();

        ArrayAdapter<RSSItem> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<RSSItem>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, data);
        setListAdapter(adapter);


}



private class GetDataRSS extends AsyncTask<Object, Void, List<RSSItem>>{

    @Override
    protected List<RSSItem> doInBackground(Object... params) {
            RSSPullParser parser = new RSSPullParser();
            List<RSSItem> items = parser.parseXML();
            return items;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<RSSItem> result) {
            data = result;

    }
}
```

but, after run my program, I'm getting below error:

```
06-30 07:35:45.777: E/AndroidRuntime(25093): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-30 07:35:45.777: E/AndroidRuntime(25093): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.parsingrss/com.example.parsingrss.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-30 07:35:45.777: E/AndroidRuntime(25093):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2071)
06-30 07:35:45.777: E/AndroidRuntime(25093):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2096)
06-30 07:35:45.777: E/AndroidRuntime(25093):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:138)
06-30 07:35:45.777: E/AndroidRuntime(25093):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1207)
06-30 07:35:45.777: E/AndroidRuntime(25093):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-30 07:35:45.777: E/AndroidRuntime(25093):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:213)
06-30 07:35:45.777: E/AndroidRuntime(25093):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4787)
06-30 07:35:45.777: E/AndroidRuntime(25093):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-30 07:35:45.777: E/AndroidRuntime(25093):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-30 07:35:45.777: E/AndroidRuntime(25093):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
06-30 07:35:45.777: E/AndroidRuntime(25093):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:556)
06-30 07:35:45.777: E/AndroidRuntime(25093):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-30 07:35:45.777: E/AndroidRuntime(25093): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-30 07:35:45.777: E/AndroidRuntime(25093):    at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getCount(ArrayAdapter.java:330)
06-30 07:35:45.777: E/AndroidRuntime(25093):    at android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(ListView.java:465)
06-30 07:35:45.777: E/AndroidRuntime(25093):    at android.app.ListActivity.setListAdapter(ListActivity.java:265)
06-30 07:35:45.777: E/AndroidRuntime(25093):    at com.example.parsingrss.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:26)
06-30 07:35:45.777: E/AndroidRuntime(25093):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
06-30 07:35:45.777: E/AndroidRuntime(25093):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
06-30 07:35:45.777: E/AndroidRuntime(25093):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2035)
06-30 07:35:45.777: E/AndroidRuntime(25093):    ... 11 more
```

after long time debugging, finally I solved my problem this way:

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(List<RSSItem> result) {
    data = result;
    ArrayAdapter<RSSItem> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<RSSItem>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, data);
    setListAdapter(adapter);

}
```

it seems that would be null when I use that in `onCreate` method. but my question is that, why I can't use `data` variable inside UI thread(MainActivity)?
**Thanks in advance.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Actually AsyncTask runs in different thread So AsyncTask thread and main thread running simultaniously.**

So before completing the data fetching from network, your Adapter class has been called and at that time there is no any data in data variable. so NullPointerException occured.

and your following solution is working because onPostExecute is called after fetching data.

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(List<RSSItem> result) {
    data = result;
    ArrayAdapter<RSSItem> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<RSSItem>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, data);
    setListAdapter(adapter);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can.  But when you first try to use it, it isn't initialized so you have an error.  Initialize it to an empty list and you should be fine.

Comment: I initialized `data` this way: `protected List<RSSItem> data = new ArrayList<RSSItem>();`, error goes away, but still isn't working.

Comment: That is because AsyncTask is Asynchronous and it runs on different thread. If you write ` ArrayAdapter<RSSItem> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<RSSItem>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, data);
        setListAdapter(adapter);` in UI thread it will be executed immediately (it will not wait for response from AsyncTask). At the same time AsyncTask will be running in different thread.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Asyantask or thread mechenis for such type of network call.

Here is very simple example of Network operation

```
class NetworkOperation extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, String>
{

    public NetworkOperation (){

        // Public constructor
   }


    protected void onPreExecute (){

        // before request created
        Log.d("PreExceute","On pre Exceute......");

    }

    protected String doInBackground(Void...arg0) {

        // do your network operation here.

        Log.d("DoINBackGround","On doInBackground...");

        return "You are at PostExecute";
    }


    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        // After network completed, you will getresult here.
        Log.d(""+result);

    }
}
```

Comment: Give a public Constructor in AsycTask.